# How to perform same state transitions for multiple actions in a Reducer

Tags: angular, ngrx, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, ngrx-store

I have created unique Actions for My App as per the suggestions of Mike Ryan in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmnsEvoy-gY&feature=youtu.be)
But I have some Actions causing the same state transitions. How to achieve the same state transition without by-passing the Best Practices i.e., calling a common Action for two different events?

**My Actions are**

```
export const rawSignalEditInplace = createAction(
  RawSignalsActionTypes.RAW_SIGNAL_EDIT_INPLACE,
  props<{ signal: RawSignal }>()
);

export const rawSignalEdit = createAction(
  RawSignalsActionTypes.RAW_SIGNAL_EDIT,
  props<{ signal: RawSignal }>()
);
```

**My Reducer is**

```
on(rawSignalsActions.rawSignalEditInplace, (state, { signal }) => {
return {
  ...state,
  selectedRawSignal: entitiesSelectors.selectEntities(state)[signal.id]
 };
}),
on(rawSignalsActions.rawSignalEdit, (state, { signal }) => ({
  ...state,
  selectedRawSignal: entitiesSelectors.selectEntities(state)[signal.id]
})),
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can create one reducer for multiple actions:

```js
on(
  rawSignalsActions.rawSignalEditInplace,
  rawSignalsActions.rawSignalEdit,
  (state, { signal }) => {...}
)
```

Keeping your actions separate allows you to better track where actions are being dispatched from and helps you to stay modular in case you want to change things in the future. I personally recommend the multiple actions -> one reducer pattern for this reason, although others may also work.

Comment: What if the different actions receive different props?

Comment: Do you have a use case where you want to use one reducer to handle different actions with different properties?

Comment: yes that's what I had but I solved  it by designing it in a different way

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a design issue. If there are different properties, they're probably sufficiently different actions to warrant having their own reducers. Out of curiosity, is that the solution you chose?

Comment: I had a state change that I wanted 2 actions to trigger, but they each had also different state changes. instead of putting this common state change in both reducers, I wanted to have one reducer that listens to both actions and does it, so if one day I want another action to also do the same I can just add it to the reducer. But then I realized I don't need this state change to happen at all, rather I can put that logic it in the state's selector.

Comment: Awesome, glad you found your solution. We often overlook the selector as the main tool of extracting information from the state.